# Redirect My Website Home to Web

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-hosting

I have hosted my asp.net site to GoDaddy. site always Redirect to http://www.bminternational.co.in/BM-Home.aspx but i want to redirect to http://www.bminternational.co.in for home page rather than previous one.

Where i have to make changes in Godaddy plesk or in my Home.aspx Page

This is my config snap in GoDaddy Web Hosting.
[image]

Comment: There must be a config issue! look out for the starter page. usually home or index names are considered as a default execution.

Comment: my home page name i have kept as BM-Home.aspx as i have said.. now is there any way to show it as only web rather to show page name.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer.

before i have written default.aspx and redirect it to Response.redirect()
but now change it to Server.Transfer().
and this solved my problem.